# How to call an third party exe within my C# application?

Tags: c#

I am writing an C# application. In my application, I need to call a third party exe that reads a text input file generated by my application. Then, the third party exe does calculation and writes calculation results into a text file so that I can read the results back for post-processing.
How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is rather vague ... Did you write this other program, do you need to start it, ect... you need to be more specific

Comment: Start with the [Process Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2):

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path_to_exe);`

Microsoft documentation explains the additional parameters you can pass into the method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0